# How to handle pressed button more time in Kivy?

Tags: python-2.7, button, kivy

I started a Kivy a while ago. I would like to react on the button down, same way as the on_key_down. It is there something that possible, or do it the right way?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.button = Button(text='Button', size_hint=(1, None))
        # When button is up
        self.button.bind(on_release=self.on_release)
        # When button is pressed
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.on_press)
        # Call update every n seconds
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/10.01)
        return self.button

    def on_release(self, *args):
        print self.button.state

    def on_press(self, *args):
        print self.button.state

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.button.state == 'down':
            print 'move', dt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: You have it in the update. While the `self.button.state`  will be down assume that the button is pressed. Actually don't assume, is pressed.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking... The callback triggered when a button is pressed is on_press, which you have above.